# Where are the images read in this classification python program?

Tags: tensorflow, classification

I am looking at this python [code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/tensorflow-without-a-phd/blob/master/tensorflow-mnist-tutorial/mnist_2.1_five_layers_relu_lrdecay.py) by Dr. Martin where it does handwritten number identification. I am trying to understand where I could insert my own images and labels for classification. I could not find where it does read number images and labels.

This code is at Github [folder](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/tensorflow-without-a-phd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses predefined MNIST dataset:

```
import mnistdata
```

Data is read at line 38:

```
mnist = mnistdata.read_data_sets("data", one_hot=True, reshape=False)
```

And it's fed into a network here:

```
    batch_X, batch_Y = mnist.train.next_batch(100)

    # compute training values for visualisation
    if update_train_data:
        a, c, im, w, b, l = sess.run([accuracy, cross_entropy, I, allweights, allbiases, lr],
                                 feed_dict={X: batch_X, Y_: batch_Y, step: i})
```

Comment: Appreciate your quick help

Comment: If your problem is solved, don't forget to mark the question as solved.

Comment: Sure, extra question, where does it actually point to the image folder?  I want to point this to my folder with all images.

Comment: @PCG I think that would be pretty difficult to use. Try studying this tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/images), it would be the best way foe you to import your own daa.